# BCC transferred to BTC wallet on trezor

Tags: bitcoin-cash

i made transfer of BCCto my trezor walltet from an online exchange, but by mistake entered my BTC address of trezor, exchange shows transaction is completed. how to recover the same.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps from "How to claim your Bitcoin Cash (Bcash)" by Trezor Blog should do the trick.

https://blog.trezor.io/claim-bcash-bitcoin-cash-bch-bcc-trezor-wallet-f0a810d5864a

Steps:

1) Make sure Trezor uses latest firmware

2) Connect your Trezor

3) Go to [Coin splitting tool](https://trezor.io/claim-bch)

4) Receive your Bitcoin Cash